# how to use read -s with printf

Tags: shell-script, read, printf

If I use "read -s" it deletes the existing line and brings the next prompt to the same line as mentioned below. Please let me know any solution to this error. I need to use "-s" with read not to echo the password on the screen.

script:

---

```
$ cat a.sh
printf "Enter the db name : "
read -r sourcedb
printf "Enter the source db username: "
read -r sourceuser
printf "Enter the source database password: "
read -s sourcepwd;
printf "Enter the target database username: "
read -r targetuser
```

Current Output:

---

```
$ ./a.sh
Enter the db name : ora
Enter the db username: system
Enter the db password: Enter the target database username:
```

Desired Output:

---

```
$ ./a.sh
Enter the db name : ora
Enter the db username: system
Enter the db password: 
Enter the target database username:
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: What shell are you using? Your script has [no shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), and you are running it as `./a.sh` so it isn't clear what shell will be running it. What shell do you use?

Comment: sorry, Its a bash shell. #!/bin/bash.

Comment: The first sentence is partly incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/743400/edit), please? For instance, do you mean *"If I use "read -s", it deletes the existing line..."*?

Comment: Sorry, i have correct it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`-s` is not a standard option of the `read` utility. In ksh, `-s` is to save the input on the shell's history, in bash and zsh, it's to suppress the terminal echo, in most other shells, it's an invalid option, so you need to specify a she-bang and change the misleading `.sh` extension if you want to use it.

Suppressing the terminal `echo` means the CR and NL that are echoed when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will also be suppressed, so you need to send them by hand. Just print a newline before the next prompt (it will be changed to CR+NL by the terminal driver).

Prompts should also go to stderr rather than stdout which should be reserved for the output produced by your script.

```
#!/bin/bash -
printf>&2 "Enter the db name: "
read -r sourcedb
printf>&2 "Enter the source db username: "
read -r sourceuser
printf>&2 "Enter the source database password: "
IFS= read -rs sourcepwd
printf>&2 "\nEnter the target database username: "
read -r targetuser
```

The `read` builtin of both `bash` and `zsh` (the shells that support `-s` to suppress echo) support issuing the prompt by themselves (which they send to stderr). In `zsh` with:

```
read 'var?prompt'
```

Like in ksh, and in bash:

```
read -p prompt var
```

So instead of using `printf`, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash -
read -rp 'Enter the db name: ' sourcedb
read -rp 'Enter the source db username: ' sourceuser
IFS= read -rsp 'Enter the source database password: ' sourcepwd
read -rp $'\nEnter the target database username: ' targetuser
```

Comment: Am using bash shell. #!/bin/bash.  Thanks for the response. Am able to resolve it with the answer mentioned above using \n with printf. Somehow "read -s" is deleting the current line, I had to use \n\n for the printf 's next to "read -s". Anyhow it resolved my issue. Thanks a lot for the quick response and solution.

Comment: @dbadmin are you on Windows, perhaps, using WSL?

Comment: No, Am using RHEL Linux